# One definition of strong convexity (from textbook of Prof. Bertsekas in 2015)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

In [strong convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions), there are a few definitions, one of them is:

$f$ is strongly convex over $\mathcal{C}$ with coefficient $\sigma$ if $\forall x,y \in \mathcal{C}$ and all $\alpha \in [0,1]$, we have

$$f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)+ \frac{\sigma}{2}\alpha(1-\alpha)\|x-y\|^2\leq\alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y)$$

In the textbook `Convex Optimization Algorithms, Bersekas p.471`
, it says:

There exists a unique $x^* \in \mathcal{C}$ minimizing $f$ over $\mathcal{C}$, and by applying the definition above with $y=x^*$ and letting $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, we have

$$f(x) \geq f(x^*)+\frac{\sigma}{2} \|x-x^*\|^2$$

I am questioning if the conclusion is correct since if $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, there should be no the term $\frac{\sigma}{2} \|x-x^*\|^2$.

How to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $y=x^*$ gives you after a small rearrangement
$$
f(x^*+\alpha(x-x^*))-f(x^*)\le\alpha\left[-\frac{\sigma}{2}(1-\alpha)\|x-x^*\|^2+f(x)-f(x^*)\right].
$$
The left hand side is non-negative due to the assumption that $x^*$ is the minimum, that is 
$$
0\le-\frac{\sigma}{2}(1-\alpha)\|x-x^*\|^2+f(x)-f(x^*).
$$
Now let $\alpha\to 0$.